# How to enforce method execution order in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, functional-programming

Long story short, i have following class:

```
public class FlowBasePipeline<T>
{
    private List<StepBaseBusiness<T>> stepList = new List<StepBaseBusiness<T>>();
    
    public void Push(StepBaseBusiness<T> step)
    {
        stepList.Add(step);
    }
    
    public void Trigger(T result)
    {
        foreach (var step in stepList )
        {
            result = step.Execute(result);
            if (!result.IsSuccess)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is forcing programmer to call `Push` method in the first place and then give them access to `Trigger` method, in this case following scenario is not allowed

```
var pipeline=new FlowBasePipeline<MyStepResult>();
pipeline.Trigger()// Trigger method is not recognized
```

we should first call `Push` method

```
var pipeline=new FlowBasePipeline<MyStepResult>();
pipeline.Push(new MyStep()).Trigger()//Now Trigger is recognized
```

What I've done:

I applied explicit interface method implementation as follows to get it to work:

```
public interface IBasePipeline<T> where T:BaseResult,new()
{
    void Trigger();
    IBasePipeline<T> Push(StepBaseBusiness<T> step);
}


  public class FlowBasePipeline<T>:IBasePipeline<T> where T:BaseResult,new()
   {
          private List<StepBaseBusiness<T>> stepList = new List<StepBaseBusiness<T>>();
        
            public IBasePipeline<T> Push(StepBaseBusiness<T> step)
                {
                    stepList.Add(step);
                    return this;
                }
        
                void IBasePipeline<T>.Trigger(T result)
                {
                    foreach (var step in stepList )
                    {
                        result = step.Execute(result);
                        if (!result.IsSuccess)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
        
                    }
                }
    }
```

Now it works well and we don't have access to `Trigger` method before `Push` method, but from my prospective it's not a good way as we might need more level of orders and i don't know how it could be done in this way.

As i know, method chaining is one of the key rules of functional programming.

Is there any pattern or strategy to implement this kind of chaining?

**Update**:

we need to call push method multiple times

```
var pipeline=new FlowBasePipeline<MyStepResult>();
pipeline.Push(new MyStep1()).Push(new MyStep2()).Trigger();
```

After first push, push and trigger would be available.

Comment: Have `Push` return something with a `Trigger` method on it.

Comment: As a side note, please could you reformat your code? I suspect it doesn't look like this in Visual Studio, and it's *really* hard to read with the indentation all the place like this.

Comment: You can try considering Builder Pattern. Calling the build() method will return the final object which you can use to call trigger

Comment: @mjwills you are right but I,m looking for the most efficient way, is it the best way? please share your code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet reformed .

Comment: Is that *really* how it looks in Visual Studio? I'd be quite surprised. For example, in the very first two lines... is your class declaration really at the same level of indentation as the declaration for `stepList`? If it's poorly formatted in Visual Studio too, I'd get VS to reformat it to start with... then make sure it looks nice here. It's always worth taking the time to make the code in a post look as readable as possible... read through the post and ask yourself whether that's how *you'd* want to read it if you were answering the question.

Comment: Is it valid for a consumer to `Push` but never `Trigger`? Or to `Trigger` multiple times after a single `Push`? If not, seems it should be a single method that invokes a callback between the "push" and "trigger" parts of its action.

Comment: call push multiple times in a row and then call trigger method just one time.

Comment: If you want to read more about this type of design issue it goes under the name of "temporal coupling".

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to use interfaces to restrict access to specific methods by specifying an interface as the result.

```
public interface IStartCar
{
  IDriveCar Start(string key);
}

public interface IDriveCar
{
  IParkCar Drive(string address);
}

public interface IParkCar
{
  IStopCar Park();
}

public interface IStopCar
{
  IParkCar Drive(string address);
  void Stop();
}

public class Car : IStartCar, IDriveCar, IParkCar, IStopCar
{
  public IDriveCar Start(string key);
  public IParkCar Drive(string address);
  public IStopCar Park();
  public IStopCar Park();

  private Car() { }

  public static IStartCar Get()
  {
    var result = new Car();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now to get a Car you use the CarFactory method `Get()`, it returns a car, but you really only have access to the interface result.  This pattern only allows developers to string specific methods together:

```
var car = Car.Get();
car.Start("key").Drive("address1").Park().Drive("address2").Park().Stop();
```

Comment: I like the solution and it reads easy.  Worth noting, even if it should be a giant red flag to someone, developers could break this pretty easily with reflection or simply casting.  I've seen juniors do some wild stuff.  If you _really_ want to stop developers from doing X in code I've typically enforced it somewhere in the build pipeline.  Like preventing code hitting the repo with any usage of `lock` for example.

Comment: @Abolfazl it's just a design.  There really isn't a *best* design because it always depends...

Comment: @Zer0 agreed.  As with everything it always *depends* on what is necessary.  This is one of the easiest to implement, but anyone could just cast the object to car and do all sorts of wild things.  However, I would really wonder what the developer was thinking in that case instead of asking other developers.

Comment: you are right but as i see , it's best use case of interface segregation ! isn't?

Comment: @Abolfazl from my knowledge, that would be a *no*.  The ISP is a practice to reduce interface methods to only those that would be used by all implementing classes.  Adding methods only used by specific implementations would break ISP.

Comment: as i updated my question if we need to call push method multiple time, your design need to change a bit @Erik Philips

Comment: @Abolfazl If you look at my pattern, you just need to adjust your interfaces to expose what you need.  My example allows someone to either `Drive()` or `Stop()` once `Park()`.

Comment: @Zer0 You can address that concern by splitting the class into multiple immutable classes that only expose the methods they support. This means more classes, but on the other hand, if you do that, you don't need the interfaces.

Comment: @Erik Philips it could be a bit complicate, when we need to expose previous method plus new method on the new interface, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Example of approach I use for api's that inherently 'guide' the callers with a fluent syntax:

```
public class Pipeline
{
    readonly List<Action> _steps = new List<Action>();
    
    // only Push is available when Pipeline is initialized
    public PipelineWithSteps Push(Action step)
    {
        _steps.Add(step);
        // or cache this if you want 'Push' repeatable
        return new PipelineWithSteps(this);
    }

    public class PipelineWithSteps
    {
        // not required but often the chained context wants/needs access to the first context
        readonly Pipeline _context;
        
        // api is public but ctor cannot be invoked by external caller
        internal PipelineWithSteps(Pipeline context) => _context = context;
        
        // now Trigger is available only after something was pushed
        public PipelineWithSteps Trigger()
        {
            foreach(var step in _context._steps)
                step();
            Console.WriteLine();
            return this;
        }
        
        // usually I don't repeat an initialization method;
        // this could be done using the 'context' 
        // but would have to be refactored to return the existing 'PipelineWithSteps'
        public PipelineWithSteps Push(Action step)
        {
            _context._steps.Add(step);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    var pipeline = new Pipeline();
    pipeline.Push(() => Console.WriteLine("A"))
            .Push(() => Console.WriteLine("B"))
            .Trigger()
            .Push(() => Console.WriteLine("C"))
            .Trigger();
```

Output:

```
A
B

A
B
C
```

Comment: well done.but it would have been good to use contracts in your design.

Comment: @Abolfazl Absolutely. Just keeping it bare-bones for clarity

Answer (score 0):

After hours ,i came up with this design:

```
   public interface IBasePipelineRegister<T> where T:BaseResult
    {
       IStagePipeline<T> Push(StepBaseBusiness<T> step);
       List<StepBaseBusiness<T>> Steps { get; set; }
    }


   public interface IBasePipelineTrigger<T> where T:BaseResult
    {
        void Trigger(T result);
    }

   public interface IStagePipeline<T>: IBasePipelineTrigger<T>,IBasePipelineRegister<T> where T:BaseResult 
    {

    }

   public class FlowBasePipeline<TResult> : IBasePipelineRegister<TResult> where TResult : BaseResult,new()
    {
        public List<StepBaseBusiness<TResult>> Steps { get ; set ; }
        private IStagePipeline<TResult> _stagePipeline;
        public BasePipeline()
        {
            this.Steps = new List<StepBaseBusiness<TResult>>();
            this._stagePipeline = new StagePipeline<TResult>(this);
        }
        public IStagePipeline<TResult> Push(StepBaseBusiness<TResult> step)
        {
            Steps.Add(step);
            return _stagePipeline;

        }
    }
```

As you see, `BasePipeline` just implements `IBasePipelineRegister` and Register method presents new StagePipeline class that is consist of current class plus trigger implementation.

```
public class StagePipeline<T>: IStagePipeline<T> where T:BaseResult
{
    private readonly IBasePipelineRegister<T> pipelineRegister;
    public List<StepBaseBusiness<T>> Steps { get; set; }

    public StagePipeline(IBasePipelineRegister<T> pipelineRegister)
    {           
        this.pipelineRegister = pipelineRegister;
        Steps = pipelineRegister.Steps;
    }


    public IStagePipeline<T> Push(StepBaseBusiness<T> step)
    {
       return pipelineRegister.Push(step);
    }

    public void Trigger(T result)
    {
        foreach (var step in Steps)
        {
            result = step.Execute(result);
            if (!result.IsSuccess)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Now each method adds a new feature not replacing new one.

```
var pipeline=new FlowBasePipeline<MyStepResult>();
pipeline.Push(new MyStep1()).Push(new MyStep2()).Trigger();
```

Comment: it seems you are making use of decorator pattern , new feature is added to new mothod?

Comment: maybe, but i tried to respect functional programming as much as possible.